# How do I customise the 404 page?

Tags: docusaurus

I would like to know how to change the text on the 404 page to be custom not the generic message. How would I go about this? The standard 404 page looks like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYFLZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `swizzle` it.

**1)** Open a Terminal/Power Shell inside your `docusaurus` folder.

**2)** Run:

```
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic NotFound
```

**3)** Edit the file `src/theme/NotFound.js`.

---

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/discussions/6030